# Stop and Play Songs

Tags: java, javasound

I need help in my server. I successfully play songs after receiving certain messages but when i receive stop it stops the song but crashes the server. I thank you in advance for your help

```
    public class server
{
    private static final int PORT = 7777;

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String filename;  
    private static  Clip clip4;
    static Player player; 

    public server(String filename) {  
        this.filename = filename;  


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

    {


        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());

            System.out.println("IP:  " + serverSocket.getInetAddress() + "  Port:  " +  serverSocket.getLocalPort());

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 7777");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 7777");

        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); 
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();


                System.out.println(message);{
                clip4 = null;
     if (message.equals("rock1")) {

                    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("D:/Andrd/Music/TheAll-AmericanRejects-Swing,Swing.wav"));
                      clip4 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                      clip4.open(inputStream);
                      clip4.start(); 

                } else if (message.equals("stop") && clip4 = null && clip4.isRunning()){
                     clip4.stop();
                 }
 }


                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();


            }catch (IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }


        } 
        }

}
```

This is what my console looks like after executing this code

```
 IP:  Timskie-PC/192.168.1.118  Port:  7777
    Server started. Listening to the port 7777
    rock1
    stop
```

but still doesnt stop the song

Comment: `if (message.equals("rock1")) {`  If that is true, then logically `if (message.equals("stop")) {` **cannot** be true.  Why are you surprised at the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Clip clip4 = null; // Make this a member variable.
...
if (message.equals("rock1")) {
  AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("D:/Andrd/Music/TheAll-AmericanRejects-Swing,Swing.wav"));
  clip4 = AudioSystem.getClip();
  clip4.open(inputStream);
  clip4.start();
} else if (message.equals("stop") && clip4 != null && clip4.isRunning())
  clip4.stop();
}
```

**EDIT**

Notice that `Clip clip4 = null;` is not a member variable. It is declared inside the while loop. Each time the loop iterates, it is being redeclared. If you declare it as a Class level "member variable" you will get a different result.

Comment: `if (message.equals("stop")) {` should most efficiently be `else if (message.equals("stop")) {`

Comment: There is probably another reason why this is happening. Posting a more detailed example of your code will help identify the problem you're having.

Comment: @axiopisty I've tried ur suggestion yea it stops the song but it gets this error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"
 at server.main(server.java:146)
plus the message "stop"

Comment: see my previous comment.

Comment: See the edit I made to my answer. Notice, you didn't actually make clip4 a member variable yet. It is causing your NPE. Please don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer again. I think that since I edited the answer to reflect the newest edit you made to the OP the answer was unmarked as accepted.

Comment: @axiopisty i tried ur suggestion same results i dont know why it doesnt do the clip.stop

Comment: I really need help about this problem please im begging anyone to help me :(